# DeltaImport fetches all the data

Tags: solr, dih

I'm indexing data from database. I'm using delta import to fetch the recently updated data. However, I find that it is fetching the whole data twice and processing it once though the changes are applicable to only one row.

[image]

My config.xml where deltaquery is given:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.github.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver" url="jdbc:c*://127.0.0.1:9042/test" autoCommit="true" rowLimit = '-1' batchSize="-1"/>
<document name="content">
    <entity name="test" query="SELECT * from person" deltaImportQuery="select * from person where seq=${dataimporter.delta.seq}" deltaQuery="select seq from person where last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' ALLOW FILTERING" autoCommit="true">
        <field column="seq" name="id" />
        <field column="last" name="last_s" />
        <field column="first" name="first_s" />
        <field column="city" name="city_s" />
        <field column="zip" name="zip_s" />
        <field column="street" name="street_s" />
        <field column="age" name="age_s" />
        <field column="state" name="state_s" />
        <field column="dollar" name="dollar_s" />
        <field column="pick" name="pick_s" />
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

There are about 2100000 rows. So it always cause a large memory consumption resulting in Running Out of Memory. What could be the problem? Or does it work in this way only?

Comment: Have you checked the dataimport.properties file? Does it have the last index timestamp updated??

Comment: Yes, it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If solr is running out of memory then it is time to add more memory to the solr box. Adding more RAM will help alleviate the issue.